# Ruby - Songkick api - Need help with events.location() query

Tags: ruby, api, location

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jrmehle/songkickr) Songkick wrapper and it works for getting grabbing events by artist like so:

```
sk.events(:artist_name => "Balimurphy")
```

But I'm having trouble grabbing events by location. Songkick is expecting the query to look like this

```
location=geo:lat,lng
```

I'm having trouble finding the right syntax to pass lng=-73.5833, lat=45.5. Here are some variations I've tried:

```
sk.events(:location => :geo=>{:lng=>"-73.5833", :lat=>"45.5"})
sk.events(:location => {:geo=>lng=-73.5833, lat=45.5})
sk.events(:location => "geo=-73.5833,45.5")
```

Any ideas?

Where can I find documentation that might cover this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking through the following 3 sources:

- https://github.com/jrmehle/songkickr
- http://rubydoc.info/gems/songkickr/0.1.0/frames
- http://www.songkick.com/developer/event-search

and I think you need to change your last attempt to

```
sk.events(:location => "geo:-73.5833,45.5")     # geo:
```

One example on the songkick page has `location=ip:94.228.36.39`. This makes me think that it for location, it wants `location=type:data`.

I assume that the hash you pass gets turned into `key=value` (just looking at the songkick page and your working example).

Therefore, you would want your value to be "geo:-73.5833,45.5" and your key to be "location".

I hope this works for you!

Comment: (Disclosure: I work at Songkick.)
This is indeed correct! There's a mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/songkick-api, where several of us are listening if you have any questions or suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried this as well and it's not working for me.

Comment: Could be an issue with the wrapper. I have resorted to using :location  => "ip:x.x.x.x" as temporary workaround while I edumacate myself in the dark arts of Ruby. Thanks!

Comment: @spectro I hope you get it working! It seems like using the `ip:x.x.x.x` method might be more effective anyways, at least from their website. @nfelger thanks for helping out!